# Import Text File by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

this is the problem every time i run it instead of update the old data that i import, it push old data to right side.

anyone can help me on 
this i want to import text file to the particular area also contain text delimited after import  as you can see from below

like import file from to column A3 to z3 something like that i cant find right word to explain it

```
Sub import()
    rPaht = Sheet5.Range("a1")
    rFileName = Sheet5.Range("b1")
    Sheet5.Range("a4").CurrentRegion.Offset(500, 0).Resize(, 40).Clear
    With Sheet5.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & rPaht & "\" & rFileName & ".txt", Destination:=Sheet5.Range("$A$4"))
        .Name = Sheet5.Range("b1").Value
        .TextFilePlatform = 874
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "?"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    End With
    Sheet5.Range("a1") = rPaht
    Sheet5.Range("b2") = rFileName
End Sub
```

if you can suggest any new kind of code i would be thankful

explaination include is the best gift for me to study coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried queryTable by `recording macro` in read a txt file into excel

I think you are missing one critical line

`.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells`

I tried `WITH` and `WITHOUT` this line, the behavior is replace and SHIFT data to right

The default value for `RefreshStyle` is `xlInsertDeleteCells` -- `Partial rows are inserted or deleted to match the exact number of rows required for the new recordset.`

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb209094%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: where should i put the missing line and where should i delete unwanted line of code

i tried to put but it is still

Shift data to the right